# Intellij: How to bring editor into focus from terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using the embedded terminal in intellij. Now I want to put my cursor on the editor (and not close the terminal).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I am always using just <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get from terminal to the editor and <kbd>Alt + F12</kbd> to get back to the terminal. Doesn't it fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "Pinned Mode" on your terminal. Right click near the terminal title and select "Pinned Mode".

Comment: Doesn't work for me (mine is on pinned mode already). I posted an ad-hoc solution below, but that loses benefits like reverse search.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy fix, but this loses benefits like reverse search.

```
Tools -> Terminal -> Uncheck Override IDE shortcuts
```

Comment: Unchecking this option is not required in the current IntelliJ IDEA version, this issue was fixed recently. ESC works just fine by default.